# What can I use to increase the height of my fence?

Tags: fence

A fire just burnt the back of my hedge fence so that now people in the street behind can see the inside of my garden (where my little girl plays) and even enter it.

My landlord is about to install wooden fences, probably [of that kind](http://www.wickes.co.uk/Wickes-Overlap-Fence-Panel-6ft-x-6ft/p/540053). But I'm afraid a tiptoeing man will still be able to look over the fence and see inside the garden (sidenote: they're also incredibly flimsy hence not good for security, I don't really understand how this type of fence is the norm but whatever)

Is there any way to somehow put things on top of the fence to increase their height (for privacy)? Bonus question: any idea to increase security too?

Comment: I would never rely on a fence, a hedge,or anything else to insure the security of my children.When my children were small and   playing outside, either myself, my wife, or one of my neighbors, was on patrol. Our children were never totally alone. They were too valuable an asset.

Comment: The best path is to dialogue with your landlord about the fence you want and pay the difference.   Far better and cheaper to buy the right fence than buy the wrong fence and try to cheese something together to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Lattice Fence Topper" + Clematis.

This is also a deterrent against intrusion - see example [police advice](https://www.staffordshire.police.uk/article/2367/Fence-and-Gate-Security)

> Diamond design trellis as a topping to your fence, makes it much harder to gain a hand or foothold.  It is also difficult to climb over (especially if entwined with prickly or thorny climbing shrubs).

Maximum fence height depends on your local authority. In the UK, nothing more than 2m is generally allowed.